# Dictionary with values as array on appending one at a time, remains empty

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, arkit

In ARKit, what I am trying to do is gather a bunch of positions of node placed in my scene and then average those out so that the node movements are not jittery as what happens while using ARKit. Hence, I have a variable declared and initialised as a Dictionary with values as an Array of vector_float3. (I am thinking this is more of a Swift problem than ARKit problem, is it?)

```
var extentOfnodesAddedInScene: [SCNNode: [vector_float3]] = [:]
```

This is related to SceneKit/ ARKit. Within the renderer function which keeps detecting and updating horizontal planes, I want to append the array of vector_float3 within.

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
    guard let planeAnchor = anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor else { return }
    ...
    extentOfnodesAddedInScene[node]?.append(planeAnchor.center)
```

But on printing this out, I am getting an empty dictionary, i.e., [:]

Another similar kind of var `var nodesAddedInScene: [SCNNode: [vector_float3]] = [:]` which I have declared and initialized when I am updating at the same time with the whole array, is working fine.

```
nodesAddedInScene[node] = [planeAnchor.center, planeAnchor.extent]
```

Since, in the last var there will only be two values, it is fine. But for the former one, I want the array within the dictionary to be a dynamically updated one. Any pointers towards how to achieve this end would be very helpful.

Comment: Make sure you initialize  `extentOfnodesAddedInScene[node]` with an empty array before trying to append an element. It is probably nil.

Comment: Apologies, it was extendOfNodes... I have it initialised as an empty dictionary already. Do you mean I should initialise the array of vector_float3 within? Such as: var extentOfnodesAddedInScene: [SCNNode: [vector_float3]] = [:[]] ? This doesn't work.

Comment: I said to initialize the key `node` with an empty array

Comment: Again, apologies if I am being a pain. I understand initialising empty Dict as [:]. I do understand initialising empty Array of Dict as [[key: value]](). However, this is a Dict of Array and not the other way around. I am not sure how do I initialise this differently than the current one in my code.

Comment: If you mean, create (initialise the array) first and then add to dict, probably that would a a way that works. Will check and get back if it does for my purposes.

Comment: try `extentOfnodesAddedInScene[node, default: []]?.append(planeAnchor.center)`

Comment: make sure your dictionary type value is an array `extentOfnodesAddedInScene:[SCNNode: [vector_float3]] = [:]`

Comment: Impressive! Works like a charm. If you would be kind enough to just copy and paste your code as an answer, I will check that for finality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Swift 4 Dictionary Key-based subscript with default value to initialize your array with an empty array to be able to append to it even when there is no value yet defined to its key. Just make sure your dictionary value type is an array `[SCNNode: [vector_float3]]`:

```
extentOfnodesAddedInScene[node, default: []].append(planeAnchor.center)
```