# Append int in array inside dictionary

Tags: ios, swift

I use this line to append `indexPath.row` in array in dictionary.

```
var downloadQ = [Int: [Int]]()
var id = 1

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    downloadQ[id]?.append(indexPath.row)
    print("downloadQ:\(downloadQ)")

}
```

And this line to check.

```
print("downloadQ:\(downloadQ)")
```

But my array not append `indexPath.row` in console I get this `downloadQ:[:]`

How to fix it?

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more with your code, So that i can help you on this

Comment: @AbhirajsinhThakore add in question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47930623/2303865

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create your dictionary it is initially empty, that is, it doesn't contain any arrays for any keys.

When you say `downloadQ[id]?.append(indexPath.row)`, `downloadQ[id]` is `nil` as you have never stored an array for key `id`.  The append is then ignored since you have conditionally unwrapped `downloadQ[id]`.

You need to handle the case where there is no array for the key.  The nil coalescing operator is a nice way to do this.  Something like

```
var theArray = downloadQ[id] ?? [Int]()
theArray.append(indexPath.row)
downloadQ[id] = theArray
```

Comment: You should use Swift 4 Dictionary Key-based subscript with default value https://stackoverflow.com/a/47930623/2303865

Answer (score 0):

e.g

```
downloadQ[1] = [1,2]
downloadQ[2] = [1,2]

var arr = downloadQ[2]
arr?.append(3)
downloadQ[2] = arr
print(downloadQ)
```

What you doing is just appending your new item into array, but you have to replace that array in your dictionary.
so, after appending your array item assign your array in dictionary.

```
downloadQ[2] = arr
print(downloadQ)
```

That's it.